# Partial mocking is not working on Model - Laravel Unit test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, eloquent, mockery

I am trying to run this very simple unit test on laravel model class. The real implementation instead of the mock keeps being called. Can anyone help me understand what’s going wrong.

```
class MockTest extends \Tests\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function simpleMockTest()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock("App\Order[save]");
        $mock->shouldReceive('save')->once()->andReturn(5);

        $this->app->instance("App\Order", $mock);

        $order = new Order();

        $this->assertEquals(5, $order->save());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the expected result because `$order` is not using the mocked instance of `App\Order`.

Using `$mock` instead will give you expected result:

````
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function simpleMockTest()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock("App\Order")
           ->makePartial();

        $mock->shouldReceive('save')->once()->andReturn(5);

        $this->app->instance("App\Order", $mock);

        $this->assertEquals(5, $mock->save());
    }
}```
````